# Evaluate the remainder efficiently

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose I'm having a number containing N 1s in the form of 1111...1 and I want to evaluate the remainder of this number divided by M. Both N and M can be large, is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: maybe if you multiply N and M by 9, add 1 to N, then compute the remainder, then subtract 1, then divide by 9

Comment: Note that $$111...11 = (10^n-1)/9$$ where $111...11$ has $n$ digits.

Answer (score 1):

9 might not be invertible modulo $M$ so the comments won't always work. Using the trick of successive squaring, you can compute the remainder modulo M of a string of $2^k$ ones and also for $10^{2^k + 1}$ as follows. Suppose you know the modulus modulo $M$ for a string of $2^k$ ones and also for $10^{2^k}$. Then by squaring the modulus of $10^{2^k}$ and taking the remainder modulo $M$ you get the modulus of $10^{2^{k+1}}$. Similarly you multiply the modulus of $2^k$ ones by the modulus of $10^{2^k + 1}$ and add the modulus of $2^k$ ones, and you get the modulus for $2^{k+1}$ ones. Once you have assembled these moduli for all $k \leq 1 + \log_2 N$, you write $N$ in binary and construct the modulus of $N$ ones by combining the pieces you have for $10^{2^k + 1}$ and a string of $2^k$ ones for various $k+1$ that index the non-zero digits in the binary expansion of $N$.

Comment: I don't quite get the last sentence. How do you "construct the modulus of N ones"?